# Closed immersion of closed fiber?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Suppose $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a morphism of schemes, and $y \in Y$ is closed point.

We know the first projection morphism $p_1: X \ $ x$_{Y} \ k(y)  \rightarrow X$ is a homeomorphism onto $f^{-1}(y)$.  Is it in fact a closed immersion of schemes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the base change of a closed immersion, hence it is also a closed immersion.

Comment: Thank you, I see it now: the associated morphism Spec $ k(y) \rightarrow Y$ is indeed a closed immersion, and that property is stable under base change.

Comment: this is of course because $y \in Y$ was a closed point to begin with.